# Taking derivative of a function that takes in a function as its parameter

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is it mathematically sound to take derivatives of functions described above? Say:

$f(y) := y(1)$, then what is
$f'$?

$f'$ is essentially $\frac{d}{dy}f(y)$;

Edit:
I would like information about:

1. Whether this is mathematically legitimate;
2. If yes, Whether f' can be calculated based on that information alone;
3. If not, when can it be calculated in general?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is possible, but you need an appropriate norm, etc.

Comment: For the above, since the function is linear, you have $Df(y)h = f(h)=h(1)$.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative

Comment: Thank you copper

Comment: I think it should be $f(y(a))$...this seems more intuitive. Now when you do y(a number) you get a constant. And then you get f(const) who's derivative is essentially just zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can consider derivatives like that but it is more complicated that what you wrote. Your function $f$ is a map from a space of functions to the real numbers. So you need a directional derivate (similar to a partial derivative). You can define the derivative of the functional $f$ at the function $y$ in the direction of the function $h$ as $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(y+th)-f(y)}{t}$ where $t$ is a real number.

You can now check which conditions $y$ and $h$ need to satisfy for this to be a well defined limit. Your $f$ is not differentiable everywhere.